# What's the best way to clean up this logic so that I don't have to keep redeclaring a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this pattern of importing the `useMediaQuery` and `useTheme` hook from MUI and then storing them in variables in each component that needs it. I would like to store the logic somewhere else and just import `isMobile` to the components that need it, should I create a custom hook or pass `isMobile` around using context or something?

```
import { useMediaQuery, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
function Component1 () {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
...

}

import { useMediaQuery, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
function Component2 () {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
...

}
```

Comment: **Should** you? ‍♂️ **Can** you? Sure, if it makes sense. If it’s a value you need “everywhere” it’d make sense to lift it up—how **best** to do that depends on app architecture, personal/team preferences, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably create `useIsMobile` hook and use it everywhere:

```
import { useMediaQuery, useTheme } from "@mui/material";

const useIsMobile = () => useMediaQuery(useTheme().breakpoints.down("sm"));
```

Usage:

```
function Component1 () {
  const isMobile = useIsMobile();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this or context.

Comment: thank you this is definitely the way for my project

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward answer is to extract the reusable code to a hook, as suggested [in the answer from Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77292959/126992), but consider as well whether you really NEED an `isMobile` check in your components. If you're only applying style or size changes based on viewport size, MUI has intelligent style attributes that understand your breakpoints, e.g.

```
<Box
  sx={{
    width: {
      xs: 100, // theme.breakpoints.up('xs')
      sm: 200, // theme.breakpoints.up('sm')
      md: 300, // theme.breakpoints.up('md')
      lg: 400, // theme.breakpoints.up('lg')
      xl: 500, // theme.breakpoints.up('xl')
    },
  }}
>
  This box has a responsive width.
</Box>
```

-- [Responsive Values in the MUI System Documentation](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/usage/#responsive-values)

Note that you need to use the MUI System components instead of the Base components. [If you're already using the Core components, you're actually using the MUI System components](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/usage/#where-to-use-mui-system) and no adjustment necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using the MUI breakpoints as much as possible but there are a few situations where I felt like this was the way to go. I agree though  I'll have to go back over some of my code and see if I can avoid using the mobile checks

Comment: No worries. Sometimes there's no other way, but I find that checking the `isMobile` flag should be a last resort. Best of luck!